# how to append a dataframe to an existing dataframe inside a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I made a simple DataFrame named `middle_dataframe` in python which looks like this and only has one row of data:
[display of the existing dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLfnt.png)
And I want to append a new dataframe generated each time in a loop to this existing dataframe. This is my program:

```
    k = 2
    for k in range(2, 32021):
        header = whole_seq_data[k]
        if header.startswith('>'):
            id_name = get_ucsc_ids(header)
            (chromosome, start_p, end_p) = get_chr_coordinates_from_string(header)
        if whole_seq_data[k + 1].startswith('[ATGC]'):
            seq = whole_seq_data[k + 1]
        df_temp = pd.DataFrame(
            {
                "ucsc_id":[id_name],
                "chromosome":[chromosome],
                "start_position":[start_p],
                "end_position":[end_p],
                "whole_sequence":[seq]
            }
        )
        middle_dataframe.append(df_temp)
        k = k + 2
```

My iterations in the for loop seems to be fine and I checked the variables that stored the correct value after using regular expression. But the middle_dataframe doesn`t have any changes. And I can not figure out why.

Comment: `k = k + 2` will not do anything since at the beginning of each iteration, `k` is assigned to the next integer value between 2 and 32021. If you want to skip every other number, change your `range` function to this: `range(2, 32021, 2)` (and also the first line isn't necessary).

Comment: Got it now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `DataFrame.append` method *returns* the result of the append, rather than appending in-place ([link to the official docs on `append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)). The fix should be to replace this line:

```
        middle_dataframe.append(df_temp)
```

with this:

```
    middle_dataframe = middle_dataframe.append(df_temp)
```

Depending on how that works with your data, you might need also to pass in the parameter `ignore_index=True`.

The docs warn that appending one row at a time to a DataFrame can be more computationally intensive than building a python list and converting it into a DataFrame all at once. That's something to look into if your current approach ends up too slow for your purposes.

Comment: @Anqi, great to hear!